# Delooping monoidal $(\infty,1)$-categories into $(\infty,2)$-categories

Tags: ct.category-theory, higher-category-theory, monoidal-categories, infinity-categories

This is the one categorical level higher version of the question [*Delooping monoidal $\infty$-groupoids into $\infty$-categories*](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/404210).

**The classical, bicategorical, setting.**

Given a monoidal category $(\mathcal{C},\otimes,\mathbf{1}_{\mathcal{C}})$, we have a bicategory $\mathbf{B}\mathcal{C}$, categorifying the classical [delooping](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/delooping#delooping_of_a_group_to_a_groupoid) of a monoid into a one-object category.

It is characterised by the following property: for any other bicategory $\mathcal{D}$, we have an equivalence of categories
$$
\left\{
\begin{gathered}
\text{pseudofunctors}\\
\mathbf{B}\mathcal{C}\to\mathcal{D}
\end{gathered}
\right\}
\cong
\left\{
\begin{aligned}
&\text{pairs $(X,\phi)$ with}\\
&\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\text{- $X$ an object of $\mathcal{D}$;}\\
&\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\text{- $\phi$ a strong monoidal functor}\\
&\text{from $\left(\mathcal{C},\otimes,\mathbf{1}\right)$ to $\left(\mathsf{Hom}_{\mathcal{D}}(X,X),\right.$}\\
&\text{$\left.\circ,\mathrm{id}_{X}\right)$.}
\end{aligned}
\right\}.
$$
For example:

- A pseudofunctor $\mathbf{B}\mathbb{F}\to\mathcal{C}$ is the same as an *endomorphism* $A\to A$ of $\mathcal{C}$;
- A pseudofunctor $\mathbf{B}\tau_{\leq1}\mathbb{S}\to\mathcal{C}$ is the same as an *automorphism* $A\to A$ of $\mathcal{C}$.

**The $(\infty,2)$-categorical setting.**

**Preliminary Question.** Given an $(\infty,2)$-category $\mathcal{C}$, is there a natural monoidal $\infty$-category structure on $\mathrm{Hom}_{\mathcal{C}}(X,X)$?

**Main Question.** Is there an analogous delooping construction from monoidal $\infty$-categories to $(\infty,2)$-categories, such that, similarly to the above:

- A [functor](https://kerodon.net/tag/01Y4) from $\mathbf{B}\mathcal{C}$ to another $(\infty,2)$-category $\mathcal{D}$;

is the same as

- An object $X$ of $\mathcal{D}$ together with a functor of monoidal (?) $(\infty,1)$-categories $\mathcal{C}\to\mathrm{Hom}_{\mathcal{D}}(X,X)$,

and such that this bijection can be made into a full-fledged isomorphism of (appropriate) $\infty$-categories?

Comment: A good keyword is [delooping hypothesis](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/delooping+hypothesis); as indicated in the references at the end of the nlab page a version of it is proved in [Gepner-Haugseng's paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1312.3178.pdf), as Cors. 6.3.7 and 6.3.13 (for the $\mathbb{E}_n$-monoidal generalisation).

Comment: @DavidKern Thanks, this is a wonderful reference!